# If a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ prove $f$ is integrable on $ [a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions on $[a,b]$, and if $f_n \rightrightarrows f$  on  $[a, b]$, prove that $f$ is integrable and $\int_a^b |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$.

**My Attempt:** The sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ provided for each $e > 0$, there is an
index $N$ for which $|f - f_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.

I want to prove that $\int_a^b | f_n - f | \rightarrow 0$

What property or theorem do i have to use to solve this problem.

Comment: What does the double arrow mean?

Comment: uniform convergent

Comment: What about Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem? So, perhaps find a dominating function...

Comment: Hint: the integral is monotone/positive and the domain has finite measure. It basically in your question ...

Comment: You can either use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem or prove it directly. The direct proof is very short.

Comment: $|\int\limits_{a}^{b}{|f_n-f|d\mu}|<\epsilon\cdot \mu([a,b])$ for big enough $n$

Comment: @Svetoslav : Well, it seems the "$f$ is integrable" part is where you need some theorem.

Comment: $|\int\limits_{a}^{b}{|f_n-f|d\mu}|<\int\limits_{a}^{b}{|f_n-f|} d\mu <|f_n-f|\mu([a,b]) <\epsilon\cdot \mu([a,b]) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @Lucas : The last part of your chain of inequalities does not quite make sense.  If you have $\epsilon \mu([a,b])$, those things do not depend on $n$ and hence do not converge to 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Lucas : Also:  I would use "$\leq$" rather than "$<$."  Also, it would be good to define what you mean by $|f_n-f|$.  How is that different from, say, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ for a particular $x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: @Michael correct, i should have $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is measurable as a pointwise limit of measurable functions.
For the integrability of $f$: For big enough $n\in\mathbb N$ because of the uniform convergence we have $|f_n-f|\leq \epsilon\Rightarrow |f|-|f_n|\leq\epsilon$. Therefore 
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}{|f|d\mu}\leq \int\limits_{a}^{b}{(|f_n|+\epsilon)d\mu}$$ and we conclude that $f$ is  summable.

Further, for each $\epsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb N: n>N\Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{b-a},\,\,\forall x\in [a,b]\Rightarrow$
$\left|\int\limits_{a}^{b}{|f_n-f|d\mu}\right|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\cdot \mu([a,b])=\epsilon$ for $n>N$

Comment: I see, first part proves that the $f$ is integral and the second part proves that $\int_a^b |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Right ! I had some troubles till I write it concisely :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use upper and lower integrals for $f$, if $f-f_n<\epsilon$ you have:

$\int f_n dx+\epsilon m \ge \int^* fdx \ge\int_* fdx \ge \int f_n dx-\epsilon m$

where $m$ is the measure of the set you're integrating over. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small you have $\int^* fdx = \int_*f dx$ and consequently $f$ is integrable. The rest should be straight forward.